# C++ Assigning Giant Int Arrays

Tags: c++

I was writing a Sieve Of Eratosthenes program in C++ and I've been wanting to run the program with giant values e.g. 200000000+ for benchmarking / why not purposes.

```
void SieveOfEratosthenes(long int n)
{
    int* prime;
    prime = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * n+1);

    for (long int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++) {
        prime[i] = 1;
    }

    long int c = 0;
    long int p = 2;
    while (p * p <= n) {
        if (prime[p] == 1) {
            for (long int i = p * p; i < n + 1; i += p) {
                prime[i] = 0;
                c++;
            }
        }
        p += 1;
    }

    std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
```

I've tried declaring the array normally with `int prime[n+1]` or `int bool prime[100...]`  and I remember trying something with vectors at some point.

A lot of the errors I get are Read/Write Access Violations.

I'm not looking for a solution specific to my code, I just want to know a method I can use to initialize large arrays.

Comment: Why not to use std::vector<int> prime(n+1, 1); ? The vector does fill its array correctly and so you can sieve away.

Answer (score 1):

Compile in x64 instead of x86. Malloc is limited to 32 bit integer limit in 32 bit build.

Answer (score 0):

```
malloc(sizeof(int) * n+1);
```

Let's use small numbers, let's say that `n` is 10. Let's say your `sizeof(int)` is `4` (a very reasonable assumption, but `8` will also work, if you adjust all the following math too). So. this will allocate `4*10+1`, or 41 bytes.

```
for (long int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++) {
    prime[i] = 1;
}
```

This will then populate `prime[0]` through `prime[10]`, if you work out the logic step by step. This adds up to 11 integer values, and since `sizeof(int)` is 4, this will scribble over 44 bytes of memory.

Unfortunately only 41 bytes were allocated, hence the resulting memory corruption and access errors.

Comment: Ok, I forgot basic order of operations in maths. My bad.
So I changed my code to
`prime = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * (n+1));` and `for (long int i = 0; i < n; i++)`
But I still get the read access violation. Have I misunderstood what you said?

Comment: No, this is exactly what I was referring to. You need to make sure you recompiled the code and you have sufficient memory. On a 64 bit platform, 200 million `int`s will require 1.6gb of RAM, are you sure your operating system can run processes that large?

Answer (score 0):

I see no essential problem with your code other than the minor issue with the order of operations:

```c
prime = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * (n+1));
```

I slightly changed the logic to get the number of primes and it works fine online with 10^9:
https://onlinegdb.com/M9fZJCZVb